# How can I combine multiple updates to a numpy array in one line of code?

Tags: python, numpy

This is an odd question to phrase, but here's my code:

```
weights[0] = weights[0] - (1 / outputY.size) * alpha * (errorDiff) * normalizedX[i][0]
weights[1] = weights[1] - (1 / outputY.size) * alpha * (errorDiff) * normalizedX[i][1]
weights[2] = weights[2] - (1 / outputY.size) * alpha * (errorDiff) * normalizedX[i][2]
```

Where `weights` and `normalizedX` are numpy arrays. Is there someway to do that in one line rather than repeat it? Alternatively, I could use a loop, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way first.

Comment: You can do a list comprehension of sorts by putting the foot loop between brackets, but it probably wouldn’t look that elegant.

Comment: wring you function and using `np.vectorize`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming weights has dimensions `(3,)` and normalised is `(n, 3)`:

```
weights = weights - (1 / outputY.size) * alpha * (errorDiff) * normalizedX[i]
```

You can also do this in place:

```
weights -= (1 / outputY.size) * alpha * (errorDiff) * normalizedX[i]
```